# SET /P Not Working After Checking For Administrator Privileges

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to force the user to run the script using administrative privileges:

```
@echo off
net session >nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    echo Success: Administrative permissions confirmed.
    echo.
    echo Please Choose:
    echo 1. Enable
    echo 2. Disable
    echo 3. Exit

    set /p choice="> "
    echo Choice: "%choice%"
) else (
    echo Failure: Please run as administrator
)
pause
```

The `net session` and `errorlevel` lines check the privilege, and this works. The weird thing is that no matter what gets entered for `choice` it behaves as if it was never initialized.

The code running inside the if block works fine by itself, so I suspect the issue has something to do with how I'm checking for privileges.

Can someone explain this behavior, and any fixes?

Comment: your `set /p` works fine. It's the `echo` that fails because the echoed [variable is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variables in batch not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-in-batch-not-behaving-as-expected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need either [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) or avoid it by reorganizing your code a bit, like:

```
@echo off
net session >nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel% == 1 (
  echo Failure: Please run as administrator
  exit 1
)
echo Success: Administrative permissions confirmed.
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you are setting a variable within an `If` block, without delaying variable expansion.

However, you don't need the if block at all, nor do you need to set a variable for the selection.

The following method uses the `||` which essentially means 'if previous command produced an error', replaces the `Set /P` command with `Choice` and uses timed pauses via the `Timeout` command:

```bat
@Echo Off
Net Session >Nul 2>&1 || (
    Echo Failure: Please run as administrator
    Timeout 3 /NoBreak >Nul
    Exit /B
)
Echo Success: Administrative permissions confirmed.
Echo=
Echo 1. Enable
Echo 2. Disable
Echo 3. Exit
Choice /C 123 /M "Please Choose"
If ErrorLevel 3 Exit /B
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo Disable
Echo Enabling
Timeout 3 /NoBreak >Nul
Exit /B
:Disable
Echo Disabling
Timeout 3 /NoBreak >Nul
Exit /B
```